# Proper format to invoke Process Task in DTS 2000

Tags: sql-server, cmd, mkdir, dts, createprocess

now Im creating a dts 2000 package in SQL 2005 IDE.
Im learning to use an "Execute Process Task". So, I want to create a new folder using this tool.
These are my steps:

1. Click "Execute Process Task"
2. Description: New PT
3. Win32 process: %ComSpec%
4. Parameters: ¿?
5. Return code: 0
6. Timeout: 2

As you can see, I need the proper format to put my commands.

thanks in advance

Command like a "D:\ mkdir hello"